# Android Studio "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing tempelates" error

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently downloaded Android Studio, but when I try to start a new Android Studio Project, I get this error "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates".

when I go to

> configure-->Project Defaults-->Project structure

and try to add an `Android SDK` location, I get another error "SDK does not contain any platforms", I made sure I downloaded the latest version of `SDK`.

why is that happening? Could anyone please help?

I've searched on Google and on here and I found similar questions but nothing helped me.

Comment: open `SDK Manager` and try to update you components from there.

Comment: what you have tried ? can you mention so that it will more helpfull

Answer (score -4):

Please, follow this step to fix the issue:

1. Run **Android Studio**
2. From Welcome Secreen Select **Configure>Project Defaults>Project Structre**
3. Select **SDK**
4. Choose **Android SDK**
5. Then **OK**
6. **Apply**